# PHP Upload Script Not Functioning

Tags: php, upload, mime-types

The following code appears to upload ZIPs, but does not in fact create the document according to the naming convention I'm using:

// Upload ZIP

```
if((isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name'][0])) && ($_FILES['arquivo']['type'] == 'application/zip, application/octet-stream') && ($_FILES['arquivo']['size'] < 1000000)){

            $arq = 'documento_'.uniqid().".zip';
            $path = '/home/domain_name_here/www/documentos/';
            $documento = $path.$arq;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $documento);
            chmod($documento, 0777);
        }
```

Not entirely sure why this isn't functioning the way it should. Seems like the files upload to temporary and fail somewhere between there and the documentos folder.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that this line contains an error:

```
$arq = 'documento_'.uniqid().".zip';
```

You have double quote instead single quote wrapping `.zip`. It should be:

```
$arq = 'documento_'.uniqid().'.zip';
```